# Can I subtract credits/returns/refunds from statement balance and incur no interest?

Tags: credit-card, india, refund

My question is basically the Indian version of [this US-based question](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/48819/114954). Another duplicate possible is [this one](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/55291/114954), but it doesn't have any country tag associated with it, so I cannot go with it. [This question](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/16549/114954) is similar too, but it talks about a situation where the refund has not yet been made.

My credit card billing cycle starts from 10<sup>th</sup> of every month. This means that all transactions from the 10<sup>th</sup> of one month to the 9<sup>th</sup> of the next month are put under one credit card statement.

Now, say on 25<sup>th</sup> December 2021, I spend ₹x. A portion of this money (say, ₹y) is refunded to my card on 11<sup>th</sup> January 2022. But, the statement for my card has already been generated for the previous billing cycle, and that includes ₹x and not the refund ₹y.

What is the minimum amount that I have to pay to avoid being charged any interest? Can I just pay (Total due from previous cycle) - ₹y? Will the bank consider the refund as a "payment" to my card account for the previous cycle?

Comment: Your minimum amount due is whatever your statement says it is. The fact that a later credit appears is only relevant for the minimum payment due on your *next* statement. At least in the US, all payments are credits, but not all credits are payments.

Comment: Yes, I read about that in one of the other questions. But if you see the 2nd question I linked, there is an answer by user Dheer which says that one has to pay "the lower amount, i.e. statement balance less of refund". This is why I am looking for an answer that works for India.

Comment: I think there is no right answer here as terms and conditions might differ from bank to bank. My bank does consider refunds as payments.